# Changeable calculations in jquery using drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

jQuery newbie needs help. I'm writing a database application for a fantasy football site. It pulls player info from the database and displays it in a table on the front end for the viewer to see. You can see a semi-functional version of it here:

http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/projections-table.php

The one piece of functionality I am having a hard time with are the TFP (total fantasy points) calculations. In the first tab at the above link, there are a series of drop down menus. Some are to choose point values (e.g. 2 pts), some are to choose increments (e.g. per 10 passing yds).

When the page first loads, those drop downs need to be pre-selected with default values and the TFP column populated with totals based on that initial calculation.

Then, the user can change those values, hit the Get TFP Scores button and the point totals in the TFP column change.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cynthia, you need to add ids to various HTML elements then some javascript something like this:

```
$(function(){
    function calcTFP(e) {
        if(e) e.preventDefault();

        var $tds, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Overall_Pts, TFP;

        $("tbody#qb tr").each(function() {
            $tds = $(this).find("td");
            Pass_Yds = Number($tds.eq(2).text());
            Pass_TDs = Number($tds.eq(3).text());
            Int = Number($tds.eq(4).text());
            Rush_Yds = Number($tds.eq(5).text());
            Rush_TDs = Number($tds.eq(6).text());

            TFP = Number($s_pass_yds_pts.val()) * Math.floor(Pass_Yds / Number($s_pass_yds_yds.val()));
            TFP += Number($s_pass_tds_pts.val()) * Pass_TDs; 
            //TFP += ........; //for Rushing yds, based on Passing yds.
            //TFP += ........; //for Rushing TDs, based on Passing TDs.
            //TFP += ........; //for Ints Thrown, based on Passing TDs.

            $tds.eq(8).text(TFP);//display calculated points in row's TFP column
        });
    }

    //Passing Yds
    var $s_pass_yds_pts = $("#s_pass_yds_pts").on('change', calcTFP);
    var $s_pass_yds_yds = $("#s_pass_yds_yds").on('change', calcTFP);

    //Passing TDs
    var $s_pass_tds_pts = $("#s_pass_tds_pts").on('change', calcTFP);

    //Rushing Yds
    //add code here based on Passing Yds

    //Rushing TDs
    //add code here based on Passing TDs

    //Int Thrown
    //add code here based on Passing TDs

    $("#b_get_TFP_scores").on('click', calcTFP);//attach calcTFP as click handler to "get_TFP_scores" button

    calcTFP();//initial calculation on page load
})
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MG5cx/)

You will see that the code is only partially worked up but there should be enough there, including comments, for you to work out how to write the rest. Once you have your mind round what's going on, adding the extra code will be very mechanistic.

You will also see that the [Get TFP Scores] button is redundant as the calculations are performed automatically (a) on page load and (b) in response to changes made to the select menus. However, I have left the button in place.

### EDIT:

The five component calcs fall into two categories :

- [Passing Yds and Rushing Yds], where the general formula is `pts = s1 * score / s2`.
- [Passing TDs, Rushing TDs and Intercepts Thrown], where the general formula is `pts = s1 * score`.

Above I have worked up two sample calcs (for Passing Yds and Passing TDs), ie. one from each category. You need to work up the other three, each based on the appropriate sample.

If you have not done so already, remember also to add (as in the demo) :

- unique ids to your `<select>` and `<tbody>` elements,
- value attributes to your `<option>` elements.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! So to add Passing TDs to the calculations, would I add:

TFP = Number($s_pass_tds_pts.val()) * Math.floor(Pass_TDs / Number($s_pass_tds_yds.val()));

and 

    var $s_pass_tds_pts = $("#s_pass_tds_pts").on('change', calcTFP);
    var $s_pass_tds_yds = $("#s_pass_tds_yds").on('change', calcTFP);

?

Comment: Cynthia, not quite. You need two types of calculation depending on whether there's one or two select menus involved. See my edits above (added text and edited code) for details.

Comment: This is perfect! Your example made everything click. I know exactly how to extrapolate this for all of the other positions now. Last question - how to get the output to be in decimals? For example, if I zero everything else out w/ the dropdowns, and set the pt value for 1pt for each 10 yds passing, the total for Vince Young should be 11.5, but it is returning a whole number of 11. I've tried a number of different things and nothing is working...

Comment: Cynthia, I assumed the fraction should be rounded down, hence integer results. For decimal output, purge `Math.floor()` and write to the table cell with eg. `$tds.eq(8).text(TFP.toFixed(1));` for one deimal place or `$tds.eq(8).text(TFP.toFixed(2));` for two decimal places.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you SO much for your help. You've been a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

First, to preselect the values you have to have the server or you have to hard code them to be preselected.  If your server is outputting them (ie from a DB) then you should just set the select to the correct values via the backend.

Now let's get to the code:

```
function calcTfp() {
   // here you are doing your calcuation
   $('tr').each(function(i) {
       var tfp = 1+2+3; // this is for you to define
       $('td:eq(8)', this).val(tfp);
   });
}
```

If you want to preselect the values on the client side you just need to Add the following:

```
function Preselect() {
   $('#passingYds').val('1 pt');  // these values depend on your implementation
   $('#passingTds').val('4 pts'); 
   // etc
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  // preSelect();  // If you want to preset values on client side
  calTfp();  // on page load do all the tfp calcs

  // when the button is clicked do the tfp calcs
  $('#btnTfp').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     calcTfp();
  });


});
```